# How should I get adjacent blocks of the same color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I'm trying to make a simple color matching game and I want to find a way to select groups of blocks of the same color.

This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loupax/yHKkg/) I'm working on, and if you run it you will see that there are issues when I try to mouse over elements at the edges of the game area, telling me that it's trying to use undefined variables

If you check below, at the `parse_quad_tree()` function you'll see I handle the case of undefined vars, but since it brakes, it means I'm wrong somewhere...

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 2d array is really nested arrays.  You need to only check the level of the array that is possibly going out of bounds:

```
var n = !!grid[x][y-1]?grid[x][y-1]:false;
var s = !!grid[x][y+1]?grid[x][y+1]:false;
var e = !!grid[x-1]?grid[x-1][y]:false;   // Instead of !!grid[x-1][y]
var w = !!grid[x+1]?grid[x+1][y]:false;   // Instead of !!grid[x+1][y]
```

In other words, when you do `array[x][y]`, javascript first retrieves `array[x]`, and then looks for index `[y]` in that retrieved array.  In your case, the first lookup is undefined (`grid[x-1]`), so it cannot look up `grid[x-1][y]`.  You are checking for undefined on the last step, when the first step is undefined.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/qWktv/

Also, if you `$(c).addClass('active')` at the beginning of `parse_quad_tree`, you will be able to highlight single blocks, and you don't have to call `.addClass('active') for each neighbor because it will happen at the beginning of the recursion.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/qWktv/1/

Comment: Even though many answers answer my question correctly, I accept this because it describes the reason my script failed better. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking if your first array var exists before calling the sub array, change,

```
var e = grid[x-1]&&!!grid[x-1][y]?grid[x-1][y]:false;
var w = grid[x+1]&&!!grid[x+1][y]?grid[x+1][y]:false;
```

Comment: You don't need to check both, because by definition of the problem the sub-array in this case will be defined.  You only need to check in the direction you are "moving".

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Doesn't matter in js, out of bounds just returns undefined, which gets handled correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your bounds

```
var n = !! (y > 0 && grid[x][y - 1]) ? grid[x][y - 1] : false;
var s = !! (y < grid[x].length-1 && grid[x][y + 1]) ? grid[x][y + 1] : false;
var e = !! (x > 0 && grid[x - 1][y]) ? grid[x - 1][y] : false;
var w = !! (x < grid.length-1 && grid[x + 1][y]) ? grid[x + 1][y] : false;
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yHKkg/64/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];` for your colors use three different css classes with a color set. This way when you need to select all of them it is as easy as `$(".blue")`.